# Ionic 3 - is it possible create animated background with photos

Tags: javascript, css, background, ionic3

In my Ionic app I would like to have a slideshow of photos as background. For example, I have the login screen with the form to be filled, and I would like to have a dynamic background with some photos that slide or, better, fade one into another.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try using [BounceJS](http://bouncejs.com/)  It's a JS library that lets you create beautiful CSS3 powered animations. Here's a [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DdqcjmHOHQ) you might find helpful.